Cannot resolve method 'setReadTimeout' in 'HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory'
I have to migrate this Spring Boot code to latest version. After Spring 6+ setReadTimeout is deprecated.
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new 
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
factory.setReadTimeout(20);
factory.setConnectTimeout(20);
factory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(20);
return new RestTemplate(factory);

According to the JavaDoc: https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.springframework/spring-web/6.0.8/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html#setReadTimeout(int)
I have to use setSoTimeout but I can't find this method. What should the proper way to migrate this code?

Read this Javadoc: https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.springframework/spring-web/6.0.8/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html#setReadTimeout(int)

setSoTimeout is not in HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory , it lies within SocketConfig.Builder class. That method has existed in that library for a while so you should be able to find it even on Spring version 5

I can't find a good solution how to migrate the code.

The SocketConfig object, where the timeout is set, is then assigned to a PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager, which then gets assigned to a HttpClient, which is then used to initialize a HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory. The complete RestTemplate bean initialization code would look something like the below:
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.ConnectionConfig;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.SocketConfig;
import org.apache.hc.core5.util.Timeout;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();

        // Connect timeout
        ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = ConnectionConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(20))
                .build();

        // Socket timeout
        SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
                .setSoTimeout(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(20))
                .build();

        // Connection request timeout
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(20))
                .build();

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig);
        connectionManager.setDefaultConnectionConfig(connectionConfig);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .build();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));

        return restTemplate;
    }
}

You would also need the httpclient5 dependency:
implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5', name: 'httpclient5', version: '5.2.3'

